# Thunderbird: Use recipient "disposable" address as sender address whe replying

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, privacy

I know you can set up thunderbird to handle multiple identities for one email address and I already use it.

Is it also possible to use disposable (plus) addresses and reply with them automatically (I don't want to reply to disposable email holders with my private one!)?

(I am using gmail)

Answer (score 0):

First of all **thunderbird automatically replies** to an email **with the recipients email**, if it **is set up as **identity**.

Apparently gmail still doesn't support [sending emails from disposable email addresses](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3598/is-there-any-way-to-send-an-email-from-a-gmail-plus-address#comment2697_3602), so you need to add each single address as an alias. But if you know what to do it will take you no longer than a minute.

1. **Add disposable addresses** as **aliases** to you **gmail account**: 
   `Inbox->Settings->"Accounts and Import"->"Send mail as: "->"Add another email address you own".`
   *(They need to have the same domain as your private inbox, i.e. googlemail.com != gmail.com)*
2. Then **add each email to thunderbird as an alias identity**: `Edit->"Account Settings"->"Manage Identities..."->Add`

Now all when replying to an email received through one of your disposable addresses it should automatically send it from that address.

*(This or something similar could also work for email providers other than google.)*